# Cant detect error in .java file

Tags: android-layout

In the following java file I have declared an imageview and TextView .

```
        int numRow = 6;
        int numCol = 4;

        TableLayout tblLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tblLayout);

        for(int i = 0; i < numRow; i++) {
            HorizontalScrollView HSV = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
            HSV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            TableRow tblRow = new TableRow(this);
            tblRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tblRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bookshelf);
          //  tblRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);

            for(int j = 0; j < numCol; j++) {

                 ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                 imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
                 imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                 TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                 textView.setText("Java Tester");
                 textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
              //   textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                //Sultan
                tblRow.addView(imageView,j);
              //  tblRow.addView(textView,j);
            }

            HSV.addView(tblRow);
            tblLayout.addView(HSV, i);
```

But the text of textview is not shown in the screen . What is the problem ?

[image]

I want to show the text "Java Tester" below of TextView . What can I do for this purpose ?

Comment: Try to uncomment  // tblRow.addView(textView,j);